# Trying to eliminate delay of filter command to match the results with conv command

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing

Blue coloured curve in the diagram is the result of using *conv* command in MATLAB for generating a Gaussian modulated signal. But I need to use *filter* command for the same purpose, resulting in magenta coloured curve. It is shifted towards right by almost 15 points which I have taken care of by discarding first 15 points, which has resulted in red coloured curve. It perfectly follows the curve of convolution command until the point pointed out in the given diagram.

I have added 15 zeros at the end of red curve to match the resultant rector length with that of *conv* command.

My question is that how can I make the red curve follow the blue cure?

My code lines are:

```
     phase = conv (integrated_signal,gaussFilter,'same'); 
     phase_1 = filter (gaussFilter,1,integrated_signal);
     delay=16;
     phase_1=phase_1(delay:end);
     phase_1(1,length(phase_2)+delay)=0;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general `conv(u,v)` produces the same result as `filter(u,1,padded_v)` where `padded_v` is `v` zero padded to a length of `length(u)+length(v)-1`. Assuming that `integrated_signal` is a row vector, this can be done with the following:

```
padded_signal = [integrated_signal zeros(1,length(gaussFilter)-1)];
% or following for column vectors:
% padded_signal = transpose([transpose(integrated_signal) zeros(1,length(gaussFilter)-1)]);
phase_1 = filter (gaussFilter,1,padded_signal);
```

Now, according to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html#inputarg_shape), 
`conv(u,v,'same')` with the `'same'` argument produces the

> Central part of the convolution of the same size as `u`.

It then only suffices to extract the same central part:

```
delay = floor(length(gaussFilter)/2);
phase_1=phase_1(delay + [1:length(integrated_signal)]);
```

Comment: got it.Thanks! :)